# How to undo changes made by a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have array `int a[n]`, and I have a function which has this array as its argument. This function takes the array, does some changes in the array, and then returns a boolean value. All I want to do is undo the changes done by the function if the returned value is false (return the array as it was). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could pass it a copy of the array. Pass the copy to the function and let it do its thing. If the return value is `true`, replace the original array with the changed copy, else don't.

Comment: this very much depends on the changes that are made. When in doubt you could simply copy the array before applying any changes to the original array

Comment: Make a copy before calling the function? A [mcve] would go a long way here.

Comment: I think this won't be practical because I'll call this function multiple times, so this means that I'll have to make multiple copies of the array which will be inefficient.

Comment: @bassel27 unless you have more domain-specific knowledge, there is no other way.

Comment: Sometimes all you have is inefficient. If it's inefficient and meets the requirements, you use it and carry on to the next problem. If it doesn't meet the requirements, you have to find a different path to the behaviour you need.

Comment: Also, *inefficient* is relative. Copying an array of 100 elements over and over is still lightning fast, especially with stack memory (like passing `std::array` by value).

Comment: You could also probably split the function in two: `bool array_needs_to_be_changed(int[] arr)` and `void actually_change_the_array(int[] arr)`.

Comment: It sounds like you are basically asking about the [strong exception guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety) but with error codes. But the same principals apply. The simplest way to achieve this is to copy the data, modify the copy and then only replace the original with the copy once you know everything that could possibly fail has succeeded.

Comment: it would be best to change style of programing. I relay recommend you read about functional programing or try code is some functional language (haskell for example). This will improve your programing skill (also in C++).

Answer (score 0):

You have to backup the input array into a local array inside of the function (Before doing changes to input array). There after write the function logic. Finally check the value which is going to return by the function. If it is **false** then copy the backup array data in to input array.

Comment: `tmp_arr` is an `int`. This isn't how you copy an array (C arrays don't have value semantics, you can't copy them with `=`) and this code won't compile.

Comment: Yes, That's true. We cannot use = operator to copy arrays. So that we have to create a tmp_arr and copy input array data into tmp_arr by using a loop. I corrected my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this however you want. There is no "one right way". It depends on the specifics of your situation. Here are a few possibilities:

1. Keep a copy of the array and revert to the copy if you need to "undo" the function.
2. Write a version of the function that goes in reverse and call that version if you want need to "undo" the function.
3. Have the function keep track of the previous values of any array entry it modifies so you can apply that tracking to revert the function.
4. Don't have the function actually modify the array but instead have it create a set of modifications. Only modify the array if you decide that's what you want to do.

I highly recommend option 4. You can have a "modified array" class that provides precisely the same API as the array that also includes a reference to the real array. It can have an `apply` member to change the real array. That way, you can just throw away the instance of the "modified array" class if you don't want to keep the changes.

Since the modified array class provides the array API, it can also modify another instance of the modified array class. This provides as many layers of nesting as you may need.